Regularity of difference of fundamental solutions to heat equation
Let $K_t^{(1)}$ and $K_t^{(2)}$ be two fundamental solutions to the heat equation $\partial_t-\Delta$ on a  non-compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, i.e.
$$(\partial_t -\Delta_x)K_t^{(i)}(x,y)=0\,,\quad \lim_{t\to 0^+}K_t^{(i)}(x,y)=\delta(x,y)\,.$$
Consider the difference $u_t(x,y):=K_t^{(1)}(x,y)-K_t^{(2)}(x,y)$, which satisfies
$(\partial_t -\Delta_x)u_t(x,y)=0$ for $t>0$ and converges distributional to zero as $t\to 0^+$. Is it true that $u_t(x,y)$ is actually continuous in $t$ all the way to $t=0$?
